# StreamProvider returning firebaseAuthStateChanges doesn't update after converting anonymous user to google user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, riverpod

I have a StreamProvider that returns authStateChanges:

```
//Provider Watch Auth state Changes
@riverpod
class UserAuth extends _$UserAuth {
  @override
  Stream<User?> build() {
    print('Stream Emitting');
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  }
}
```

Now it emits correctly when I first sign in with google account, but if the user is already signed in with anonymous and I try to convert them to a google account user nothing is getting emitted because its going from signed in to signed in with a different provider meaning no state change is occurring, how I remedy this?

my method for creating or updating google sign in:

```
  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) {
        // Handle the case when the user cancels the Google sign-in
        return;
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

      User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

      if (currentUser != null && currentUser.isAnonymous) {
        // User is signed in anonymously, link with Google account
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );

        try {
          await currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
          await currentUser.reload();
          User? updatedUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

          // Pass the user's UID and email to update the user's document
          if (updatedUser != null) {
            createOrUpdateUserDocument(updatedUser.uid, updatedUser.email!);
          }
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          // Handle specific FirebaseAuthExceptions if needed
          print("Error linking with Google: $e");
        }
      } else if (currentUser == null) {
        // User is not signed in, create a new account with Google credentials
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );

        try {
          final authResult =
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

          // Create a Firestore document for the user under the 'users' collection
          if (authResult.user != null) {
            await createOrUpdateUserDocument(
                authResult.user!.uid, authResult.user!.email!);
          }
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          // Handle specific FirebaseAuthExceptions if needed
          print("Error signing in with Google: $e");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error during Google sign-in: $e");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An auth state change listener only fires when the auth state changes, so when the user signs in or signs out. Other changes in the profile of the current user (such as linking another providers) don't cause the auth state change listener to fire.

There's another [listener though for `idTokenChanges`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/idTokenChanges.html), which fires for any change in the ID token. You'll want to listen for that to detect other changes.

Comment: That could work but the documentation is very limited so Im not sure how to implement it into my streamProvider

Comment: It's a listener, so you'd implement it very similarly to the auth state change listener. Since you're not really interested in the token itself, you can just look at `auth.currentUser` for the values once the listener fires. If you're having trouble implementing this, I'd recommend posting a new qiestion with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Comment: I have changed it the code above but it gave me this:  D/FirebaseAuth(25381): Notifying id token listeners about user   and didn't update the stream

Comment: Please don't update the original code in your question after someone posted an answer. My answer explains why `authStateChanges` doesn't fire when you link additional credentials, and that you should use an ID token listener instead. Since you now modified the question, my answer makes no sense - and thus the entire page is not useful for anyone anymore going forward. If you're having trouble implementing *that* listener, post a new question for that.

Comment: Frank with all due respect the listener answer is wrong and it does not work, so I will return the question to the original and leave it here for someone to answer as this is a common use case when using flutter with FirebaseAuth

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with Firebase support and they told me:

"The behavior you're describing is expected because authStateChanges() doesn't distinguish between different sign-in methods; it simply emits a change whenever the authentication state changes. However, there's no built-in method to specifically detect an upgrade from anonymous to permanent user status"

They did say you can try combining authStateChanges() with idTokenChanges()as the other user suggestd but they also warned me its not full proof and will require the app to reload sometimes.
turns out there is no fullprove way to do this so you will have to adjust your authentication flow, I hope firebase adds a method soon for this.